# solving the differential equation y''+t(y')^2=0

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I need to solve:

$$y''+t(y')^2=0$$

I did:

$$u = y'\implies u'= y''$$

$$u'+tu^2=0\implies u' = -tu^2 \implies \frac{u'}{u^2} = -t\implies$$
$$-\frac{1}{u} = -\frac{t^2}{2}+c_1\implies y' = u = \frac{2}{c_1+t^2}\implies$$

$$y = \int  \frac{2}{c_1+t^2} dt = \frac{2\arctan \frac{t}{\sqrt{c_1}}}{\sqrt{c_1}}+c_2$$

However, by book presents the following answer:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are right if $c_1>0.$ But for $c_1\le 0$ the final integral is not an $\arctan.$

Comment: If $c_1<0$ you can decompose the denominator